# Want to add hue angle with colorchanelmixer in ffmpeg command for Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am working with one of android app which have video filter effects feature.
I am able to apply effects using colorchannelmixer, but i want to add hue angle value in command.

Some one please help me how can i achieve this?

```
complexCommand = new String[]{"ffmpeg","-y","-i",Split_main_path + STR_uN_EffectPath,"-strict","experimental","-filter_complex","[0:v]colorchannelmixer="+ "0.8179:0.01538:0.00378:"+ "0.0:0.00698:0.99372:0.00336:"+ "0.0:0.00544:0.01068:0.98262"+ "[colorchannelmixed];"+ "[colorchannelmixed]eq=1.3:0.8:1.5:1.0:1.0:1.0:1.0:1.0[color_effect]","-map", "[color_effect]", "-map", "0:a", "-vcodec","mpeg4", "-b", "15496k", "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar","22050", Split_main_path + STR_eFfect_Path};
```

Please see above command and tell me how can i add hue command in this,(i tried several ways to add but not working)

Comment: Have you tried `hue=h=x`?

Comment: actually my problem is solved.. i found the way and its working now :)

Comment: You should provide your solution as an answer, so someone with the same problem in the future can refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

May be it helps you.

```
String[] complexCommand = { "-y" , "-i" , yourRealPath , "-vf", "hue=s=0","-preset", "ultrafast","-c:a","copy", filePath};
```